# Unable to resolve variable from properties file when tried to access as function parameter using @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

This may be silly question to ask but i'm unable to find any satisfactory solution to my problem. In java we don't have the concept of default variables so i am trying to give default value from properties file to my function parameters/arguments using @Value annotation, but i'm always getting null and i'm unable to figure why is this happening. Please help me to solve the issue or provide me some appropriate link/reference which may solve my issue.

MainApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(NetappApplication.class, args);
        Sample sample = context.getBean(Sample.class);
        System.out.println(sample.check(null));
    }

}
```

Sample.java

```
public interface Sample 
{
    public String check(String message);
}
```

SampleImpl.java

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties") 
public class SampleImpl implements Sample
{

    @Value("${test}") 
    String message1;

    @Override
    public String check(@Value("${test}") String message) 
    {
        return message;
    }

}
```

app.properties

```
test=anand
```

Comment: Well, you pass null to the method, no wonder null is what you get ;)

Comment: That is not the way `@Value` works. It doesn't apply to regular methods to automagically inject a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you **are** passing null to your method...

Perhaps what you want to do is to assign default value to `test` in case **it's not defined** in property file:

```
@Value("${test:default}");
```

Then, when properties are autowired by Spring if placeholder resolver doesn't get the value from props file, it will use what is after `:`.

The best use case for this (that I can think of) is when you create Spring configuration.

Let's say you have a configuration class: for DB access. Simply put:

```java
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

  @Value("${url:localhost}")
  String dbUrl;

  // rest for driver, user, pass etc

  public DataSource createDatasource() {
    // here you use some DataSourceBuilder to configure connection
  }
}
```

Now, when Spring application starts up, properties' values are resolved, and as I wrote above you can switch between value from property and a default value. But it is done once, when app starts and Spring creates your beans.

If you want to check incoming argument on runtime, simple null check will be enough.

```java
@Value("${test}")
String message1;

@Override
public String check(String message) {
  if (message == null) {
    return message1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mate00 for response...

But actually i want that if i pass something then message should contain the data otherwise if i don't pass anything it should take it from properties file.

Eg. System.out.println(sample.check("test"));  ->> test
System.out.println(sample.check(null));  ->> anand
System.out.println(sample.check()); // invalid syntax but if it was valid the expected result was anand

Comment: So you need to do a null check inside your method by adding a simple `if`. Properties are being resolved during context start-up.

Comment: yeah that will do...

But assuming if function is only

@Override
    public String check(@Value("${test}") String message) 
    {
        return message;
    }

Then how to call the function   ???

Comment: Actually i'm trying to implement something like mentioned here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/05/spring-value-annotation.html

The content under this section...
Injecting Values In Methods:

But in this case how to call the function from main because everytime whenever it is called the value will be overridden...

Comment: Then you need to do the check in the enclosing method. The one that will check argument, and either call `check(argument)` or return `message1`. I see no other option.

Comment: I totally agree to your point but i want to ask if we cannot use injected parameter as function argument using @VALUE annotation then what's the point of that concept or else there must be some way

Comment: The best use case for this is when you are creating configuration for your application. I will update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Please go ahead... it will be very helpful :)