# How to call a function if it's parameters are injected from properties file using @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring and saw this approach for resolving method parameter from properties file...

```
public void setUserDetails(@Value("${user.first.name}")String userName,
  @Value("${user.address}") String address) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.address = address;
}
```

but whenever i call this function the values are replaced by what i pass to function. i want to know how to call the function so that the values are fetched from properties file.

I am calling the function like...

```
setUserDetails("abc","xyz")
setUserDetails("abc",null)
setUserDetails(null,"xyz")
setUserDetails(null,null)  
setUserDetails(null)       // invalid
setUserDetails()      // invalid
```

Everytime i get what i pass not from the data from properties. Please help to find me some solution or some reference link which may be helpful...

Comment: Maybe you find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769445/what-does-the-value-annotation-in-method-do

Comment: Don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656518/unable-to-resolve-variable-from-properties-file-when-tried-to-access-as-function) over and over. As mentioned there that is not how `@Value` works and it will never work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/a/21769581/679240, that annotation won't interfere on a manual invocation of the method; instead, it will automatically invoke the method right after instantiating the bean.

As the manual states:

> Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked. [...] Bean property setter methods [as in this case] are effectively just a special case of such a general config method.

Answer (score 1):

Spring annotation works on bean creation, not during methods invocation. Suppose your class is called `UserDetails`:

```java
@Component
public class UserDetails{
 public @Value("${user.first.name}") String userName;
 public @Value("${user.address}") String address;
}
```